# How to write a lookup-table into an 28C64 parallel EEPROM?

Tags: arduino, eeprom, hex

Based on the program from this post [28C64 EEPROM Programming Using Arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62490/28c64-eeprom-programming-using-arduino), I would like to write, using Arduino Mega, a lookup-table that contains one sinewave cycle, created in Excel. I would like this table to be written in address "1" in the EEPROM. I have encoded the table in hex, but I am not sure how to split it into proper code. I would also like to read the table with the Arduino Serial Plotter instead of Serial Printer. Thanks.

[image]

sinus wave in HEX:

0004080B 0F14161C 1E23282A 2F32373A 3F43464B 4E53575B 5F63676B 6F73777B 7E83868B 8E93979A 9FA2A7AB AEB3B6BB BEC3C6CB CED3D7DA DFE2E7EA EFF2F7FA

the code:

```
#define WE 52
#define OE 51
#define CE 53
#define NUM_ADDR 3

int DP[8] = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};
int AP[] = {37, 36, 35};
byte data[] = {0xB080400, 0x1C16140F, 0x2A28231E, 0x3A37322F, 0x4B46433F, 0x5B57534E, 0x6B67635F, 0x7B77736F, 0x8B86837E, 0x9A97938E, 0xABA7A29F, 0xBBB6B3AE, 0xCBC6C3BE, 0xDAD7D3CE, 0xEAE7E2DF, 0xFAF7F2EF}; /// Sinus Lookup-Table


//------------------------ Init ----------------------------

void setupDataBus(int mode) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    pinMode(DP[i], mode);
  }
}

void setupControlPins(int mode) {
  pinMode(WE, mode);
  pinMode(OE, mode);
  pinMode(CE, mode);
}

void setupAddressBus(int mode) {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ADDR; i++) {
    pinMode(AP[i], mode);
  }
}

//------------------------ Write Byte ----------------------

void writeByte(int address, byte data) {
  setupDataBus(OUTPUT);
  setupAddressBus(OUTPUT);
  setupControlPins(OUTPUT);
  Serial.print("Write Byte: ");
  for (int b = 0; b < 7; b++) {
    digitalWrite(AP[b], bitRead(address, b));

  }
  Serial.print(address, HEX);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(data, HEX);
  Serial.println();
  delay(1);
  // Enable write
  digitalWrite(OE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(CE, LOW);
  delay(1);
  delay(10);
  for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
    digitalWrite(DP[b], bitRead(data, b));
  }
  unsigned long time_i, time_f, time;
  time_i = micros();
  // Start write
  digitalWrite(WE, LOW);
  // End write
  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  time = micros();
  Serial.println(time_f - time_i, DEC);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(OE, LOW);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(CE, HIGH);
  delay(1);

}

//------------------------ Read Byte ----------------------

byte readByte(int address) {
  setupDataBus(INPUT);
  setupAddressBus(OUTPUT);
  setupControlPins(OUTPUT);
  byte val;
  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(CE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(OE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  Serial.print("Read Byte: ");
  for (int b = 0; b < 7; b++) {
    digitalWrite(AP[b], bitRead(address, b));
  }

  Serial.print(address, HEX); /// print Address
  Serial.print(", ");
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(CE, LOW);
  delay(1); 
  digitalWrite(OE, LOW);
  delay(1);

  for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
    bitWrite(val, b, digitalRead(DP[b]));
  }

  Serial.print(val, HEX); /// print Bit
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(OE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(CE, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  Serial.println();
  return val;
}

//------------------------ SETUP ----------------------

void setup() {
  setupDataBus(OUTPUT);
  setupAddressBus(OUTPUT);
  pinMode(WE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(OE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CE, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

//------------------------ LOOP -----------------------

void loop() {
  // init
  digitalWrite(OE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Initializing pins for write...");
  delay(1000);
  //for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {
  //writeByte(i, data[i]);
  //}
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data); i++) {
    readByte(i);
  }
  while (true);
}
```

Comment: Excel supports VBA. You can just write a little code to generate and save out a file, already written in C code. Any time you change the table, just run the code to punch out the updated version of code. The rest of your code just .include's the file. Nothing fancy.

Comment: So what exactly will be exported in C? A whole table as an .include file?

Comment: I'm not sure; your question. You can write code in VBA and it will create any kind of file you want. You just write code. If you want a C include file to be exported, you can do that. If you just want a binary file on disk, you can do that. If you want to communicate with a different process on the operating system, or any other operating system on the web, you can do that. The only limit is your imagination. I was merely suggesting generation of code that can be directly consumed by your C compiler. But you do what you want. That was just my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To turn spreadsheets into C array code, I have typically done the following, although I use LibreOffice instead of Excel, there should be something similar possible.

In column F (eg F4), create a formula like `="0x"&E4&","`

At the top of column G (eg G1), `=CONCAT(F4:F66)`

Then copy the cell G1 to your Arduino sketch and surround it by:

`byte data[] = {`

`};`

It looks like your sample code has 32-bit data for the 8-bit data type, and at least one element is lacking the 0x HEX prefix.